# DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: HttpException: , uri = http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Tags: flutter, request, default, dio

#### Info

**Platform Name:** flutter

**Platform Version:** 1.24.0-8.0.pre356

**Dio Version:** 3.0.10

**Android Studio:** 4.1 / Xcode 12.3

Repro rate all the time (100%)

#### Description and Steps

When making a long request (taking approximately 2 minutes), the Interceptor of the dio returns a DioErrorType.DEFAULT but does not return the reason. Below is the image:

My Dio configuration:

```
 
Dio _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
    connectTimeout: 300 * 1000, // 5 minutes to avoid timeout
    receiveTimeout: 300 * 1000, // 5 minutes to avoid timeout
  ));
  _dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsHandler()); // custom Interceptor class
  _dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(
      responseBody: true,
      error: true,
      requestHeader: false,
      responseHeader: false,
      request: false,
      requestBody: false));
  return _dio;
```

Print of dioError Object:

```
DioError (DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: HttpException: , uri = http:/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
error:HttpException (HttpException: , uri = http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
message:""
uri:_SimpleUri (http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
hashCode:12237922
runtimeType:Type (HttpException)
request:RequestOptions
baseUrl:""
cancelToken:null
connectTimeout:300000
data:Map (1 item)
extra:Map (0 items)
followRedirects:true
headers:Map (4 items)
maxRedirects:5
method:"POST"
onReceiveProgress:null
onSendProgress:null
path:"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
queryParameters:Map (0 items)
receiveDataWhenStatusError:true
receiveTimeout:300000
requestEncoder:null
responseDecoder:null
responseType:ResponseType (ResponseType.json)
_name:"ResponseType.json"
index:0
hashCode:700155926
runtimeType:Type (ResponseType)
sendTimeout:0
validateStatus:Closure: (int) => bool
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"
hashCode:180042835
runtimeType:Type (RequestOptions)
uri:_SimpleUri (http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
response:null
type:DioErrorType (DioErrorType.DEFAULT)
hashCode:956099891
message:"HttpException: , uri = http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
runtimeType:Type (DioError)
```

EDIT:

After investigating the whole process, I discovered that it was a conflict with my backend timeout (default service timeout) and not a problem with the flutter, in fact.

Changing the server timeout the problem has been solved

Comment: did you ever find a fix to this?

Comment: After investigating the whole process, I discovered that it was a conflict with my backend timeout (default service timeout) and not a problem with the flutter, in fact.

Changing the server timeout the problem has been solved